# RxJava2 - deal with several requests to Parse server

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, rx-java, rx-java2

I have an outer request to Parse server that returns List and 2 inner requests for each List item depending on the item. I need to save all the results at once when every request has returned with success (or throw error and save nothing if at least one of them failed).
I use RxParse library and the idea was that I can delay onNext or onComplete callbacks of the outer request before both inner requests on the current iteration finished with success (so that I'd be able to save everything on the outer onComplete). I only managed to make Observable for the outer request, and experiments with flatMap etc. didn't help, outer onNexts and onComplete happened before inner requests have finished. Now (without commented experiments) it looks this way:

```
boolean[] wasError=new boolean[] {false};    
Observable<ParseObject> objects = ParseObservable.find(ParseQuery
    .getQuery(DBFields.PARSE_TABLE))); //returned List
objects
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .filter(obj->filterNeededObjects(obj, realm))
       //suppose here should be some magic
       .subscribe(
              obj -> {
                  //onNext
              },
              throwable -> {
                  wasError[0] = true;
                  //onError
              }, () -> {
                  //onComplete
              }
            );
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by outer and inner request?

Comment: @chandil03 By outer request I mean the independent one that returns List<A>. Inner ones are the two that return List<B> and List<C> respectively and depend on A.getValue() for every A in List<A> (i.e. A.getValue() condition is added to the queries).

Comment: Still not create. Are you trying to say that one request returns List<A> containing List<B> and List<C>?

Comment: @chandil03 no, A, B and C classes represent different Parse tables. Let it be People, Dogs and Cats respectively. First I query People by some conditions and then for every person from the list I query all their Dogs and all their Cats. And only when all the requests are done, I need to do smth (e.g. save to Realm db)

Comment: are B and C members of  A class?

Comment: @chandil03 nope